# maven's pom.xml ordering

Tags: maven

I want to checkout code from svn, then compile it and then copy it to a remote location and then deploy the war file. can you please provide me a sample pom.xml file in which all these tasks have been performed in the above given ordering.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that in the POM cause Maven is not Ant...you can do that by using Jenkins/Hudson or any other CI solution.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins+Hudson can do this... But It don't mean that it cannot be done in Pom.xml. We can also use combination of ant scripts in pom.xml and we can use Maven AntRun Plugin to execute them. So by maven we can checkout code from svn, then compile it and then copy it to a remote location and then deploy the war file.

Check out this [Usage Page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html)